# Upper Bound Product of Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, integral-inequality

I have an explicit pdf $p(x)$ that I want to show is *log-concave*, i.e. $\log p(x)$ is a concave function.
Under suitable assumptions, this is equivalent to showing that $p(x)$ satisfies the inequality

$$p''(x)p(x) \leq (p'(x))^2.$$

In my situation, $p(x) = \mathbb{E}[f(x,t)]$, where $t$ is uniform in some compact convex set.
Differentiating under the integral sign, I can reduce to showing that

$$\mathbb{E}[\partial_x^2 f(x,t)]\mathbb{E}[f(x,t)] \leq \mathbb{E}[\partial_x f(x,t)]^2$$

i.e. I need to bound the *product of integrals* by another (related) *product of integrals*.

What tools are there for this? There are many inequalities for bounding the *integral of products* (for example, Holder's, and variants).
I am less familiar with what options there are in this slightly different setting.

If people are particularly interested, $f(x,t) = \frac{\exp(\frac{-x^2}{\lVert \vec t\rVert_2^2})}{\lVert \vec t\rVert_2}$, and we are integrating over a (centrally symmetric) convex body $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. this is all secretly a multivariable problem (though I am trying to establish log-concavity in terms of the scalar parameter $x$).

So far, I have tried writing $(\int f(y)d\vec y)(\int g(z)d\vec z) = \int f(y)g(z)d\vec y d\vec z$ as a product of integrals over independent variables, and then tried seeing if I could get pointwise bounds on the integrands $f(y)g(z)$, which would immediately imply my desired bound.
These pointwise bounds don't hold for all parameters though --- in particular, I end up requiring that $\lVert \vec z\rVert_2^2 \geq \frac{4k^2}{4k^2-2}$ is bounded away for zero (for one of the variables in the above argument --- there are no conditions on the second variable), but in my applications the integration region is convex, *i.e.* I am integrating over a region that includes $\lVert \vec z\rVert_2 = 0$, so I cannot assume this bound.